# How to keep a reference to a thread between activity destruction and recreation?

Tags: android, multithreading

First of all, lets accept the fact that when a configuration change occurs in an activity the activity is destroyed and is recreated.

A Thread holds a reference to the activity and when a configuration change happens the activity referenced is no more valid.

So, the only solution is to change in the running thread, on the fly, the reference to the new activity.
So first of all
Before the activity is destroyed, we want to hold a reference to the running thread.

Second 
When the new activity is created, we have the old thread reference and we change its activity reference that points to the old activity into a new activity.

How can we hold a refference of a thread between activity destruction and recreation, is there any other way except the fragment technique?

Thank you

Comment: You really shouldn't have activity references in your threads, or threads in your activities. This is a big code smell. You can use a static reference as answered, but if you really want to avoid future headaches, don't do that. Follow [SOLID principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design). A UI class is for drawing the UI, not for holding references to threads doing other stuff.

Comment: ok i understand. Do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: There are many clean alternatives. You can google "Android clean architecture", but keep in mind it will most likely involve a lot of modifications to your code if you don't have any architecture currently in place. However this will save you a lot of time in the future and avoid many more mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static variable in the activity class. Just make sure that either there won't be multiple instances of the activity running at the same time, or that the thread will handle that gracefully.

Alternatively, prevent activity recreation on config changes. You do that in the manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.Booyah"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|locale|layoutDirection|uiMode|screenSize">
        <!-- More stuff -->
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel for surviving config changes plus use Coroutine instead of thread they auto-cancel the job automatically when the context is not in the scope.